# Android splash screen flicker

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, splash-screen

i have added splash screen to my app, but the splash screen only flicker for a couple miliseconds. I want to show my splash until my webview completly load.
This is my code...Thank you!

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                ...

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //hide loading image
                    findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //show webview
                    findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


            });     
            wv.loadUrl("http://myurl.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your setVisibility calls. Make the webview visible, then make the loadingImage gone. That should remove the flicker.

Comment: This:
`public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);`
I try this but it's the same, the splash still flicker.

Comment: Maybe save store the views into variables first, then call setVisibility after? That will remove the time that the code is traversing the View tree. So View v1 = findViewById(...); View v2 = findViewById(...) Then v1.setVisibility(...), v2.setVisibility(...).

Answer (score 0):

You need the code to check the loading status. Here is the sample code from [WebView reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
```

After reaching 100%, you can make splash screen disappear.

Comment: I have that code in my app. But i dont want to splash screen show every time the webview load something, only on the start of the app, while webiew load.

Comment: you can count and remember the first time in a boolean value or preference, and write conditional statement in the onPregressChanged. then the splash screen will show only one time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are required to have a splash screen otherwise I recommend not to use splash screen, just display a webview frame and a loading dialog are enough, try to make user as in-control as possible. Check this link: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/